# Styling doesn't help align Facebook button

Tags: html, css

I have a page here that has a div with an Facebook recommend button.

http://www.comehike.com/hiking.php

I put this styling around the Facebook code

```
        <div style="align:center">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=217585988283772&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false" action="recommend" font=""></fb:like>
        </div>
```

But it doesn't align to the middle of that div.  Any ideas on how to get it to center-align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div is a block-level element, so you would center it with left and right margins set to auto, and by giving it a width smaller than its parent:

```
.style-me {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 450px;
}
```

Change 450 on the div and iframe to whatever you need it to be. I'm not sure about the end result you are going for here.

Answer (score 1):

What you align is the iframe it generates not the this tag:

View the Dom using firebug or inspector you will see what i am saying

UPDATE:

It will be easier to style the parent element, for example the containing div:

```
<div class="style-me">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=217585988283772&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false" action="recommend" font=""></fb:like>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.style-me {
   ...rules
}
```